# Why is my text-to-image method returning a fully-black image?

Tags: java, image-processing, fonts

I'm trying to make a method that converts a given `String` (and `Font`) into a `BufferedImage`. However, every time I run it, it returns a fully black image. The exact size of the image seems to be correct, but all pixels are perfectly black.

Here's the code:

```
static final GraphicsEnvironment GE;
static
{
    GE = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
}
public static BufferedImage textToImage(String text, Font font)
{
    if (font == null)
        font = Font.getFont("Courier New");
    FontRenderContext frc = new FontRenderContext(new AffineTransform(), false, false);
    Rectangle2D bounds = font.getStringBounds(text, frc);
    BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(
        (int)(bounds.getWidth() + .5),
        (int)(bounds.getHeight() + .5),
        BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_BINARY
    );
    Graphics2D g = GE.createGraphics(bi);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.drawString(text, 0, 0);
    return bi;
}
```

Here's "Hello World" in the default `JOptionPane` font displayed as a `JOptionPane`'s icon:
[image: A Windows dialog titled "Hello World", containing only a small, black rectangle.]

Comment: @MadProgrammer oh crap XD  Sorry, I totally meant to put the code in. Sorry, I must be more tired than I thoguht. One moment.

Comment: @MadProgrammer alright, code added. Sorry for that ^^;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution would be to change the color...

```
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.setFont(font);
    g.drawString(text, 0, 0);
    g.dispose();
```

Text, generally, isn't rendered from the `y` position down, it draw's up AND down from the `y` position, so you'll need to use something like...

```
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    g.drawString(text, 0, fm.getAscent());
```

to get the text to appear correctly...

Also `font = Font.getFont("Courier New");` isn't doing what you think it is, this won't return the font named `"Courier New"`, but will instead attempt to load the font file called `"Courier New"`.

Try using something like...

```
    if (font == null) {
        font = new Font("Courier New", Font.PLAIN, 12);
    }
```

instead...

You might like to take a closer look at [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html) for more details